# Apache NetBeans 12.4 install hangs on WIN10 during its setup

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, netbeans-12

I was installing Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4 on a new computer under Windows 10 (Home Edition, version 10.0.19042), with JDK 1.8 (Java version "1.8.0_291") already installed, and the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable set.

The installation got stuck after accepting the license agreement, and clicking the **Next** button. See the screen shot below:

[Setup GUI froze after clicking the next button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbK0y.png)

The NetBeans' setup interface just froze there, with nothing is going on.

I restarted my computer and reinstalled, but the installation just froze again at the same step. This time I was able to check its installation log, thanks to the hint about the lock file at the second installation.

The installation log gave no error, nor any hint of the problem. See the extracted log below for the last part of the installation log:

```
[2021-08-25 14:44:06.227]: NameResolver - to parse Installation Size: {0}
[2021-08-25 14:44:06.227]: NameResolver - to parse Insufficient disk space for extracting the installation data. Additional {1} is required in {0}.
[2021-08-25 14:44:06.548]: NameResolver - to parse Insufficient disk space for extracting the installation data. Additional {1} is required in {0}.
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.407]: NameResolver - to parse Insufficient disk space for extracting the installation data. Additional {1} is required in {0}.
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.412]: NameResolver - to parse &Help!
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.413]: NameResolver - to parse < &Back
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.413]: NameResolver - to parse &Next >
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.413]: NameResolver - to parse Cancel
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.413]: NameResolver - to parse I &accept the terms in the license agreement
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.414]: NameResolver - to parse org/netbeans/installer/product/components/netbeans-license.txt
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.414]: NameResolver - to parse $R{org/netbeans/installer/product/components/netbeans-license.txt;UTF-8}
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.416]: NameResolver - to parse {0}
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.436]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.436]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.436]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.436]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.436]: NameResolver - to parse Please read the following license agreement carefully.
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.455]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2021-08-25 14:44:08.455]: NameResolver - to parse Please read the following license agreement carefully.
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.568]: NameResolver - to parse C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.4
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.569]: NameResolver - to parse 1.8.0.0.0
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.569]: NameResolver - to parse 500.0.0
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.569]: NameResolver - to parse .*
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.569]: NameResolver - to parse false
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.569]: NameResolver - to parse false
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.570]: NameResolver - to parse false
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.570]: NameResolver - to parse false
[2021-08-25 14:44:11.570]: ... use Java that is already selected for the product: D:\jdk1.8
```

There were 105G free disk space on my disk C and 135G free disk space on my disk D, so there should be no disk space problem.

Comment: [1] FYI, do not use screen shots for displaying log file extracts or any other form of text or code. Instead, just paste the text directly into your question, formatting it appropriately. [2] Also, don't link to screen shots. Instead paste the images directly into the body of the question. [3] Those _"insufficient disk space"_ messages at the start of your log extract look ominous. Verify that your drives have plenty of free space.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Windows 10 Home, but in my case with Netbeans 8.2. Like you, I am positive I have plenty of disk space. My system thinks Netbeans is installed, but hangs while loading modules during startup. After 20 seconds or so it vanishes with no visual error, but the log file shows the same NameResolver errors you have.